# Get full SQlite database information from relevant row/record when clicking listView item (which contains partial information from the row/record)

Tags: android, sqlite, android-listview, android-cursor

I have a method named `getData` that populates a `listView` from my database **limited to specified columns** from the table:

```
public ArrayList<String> getData() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String[] columns = new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_MODULE_CODE,
            KEY_MODULE_NAME, KEY_LECTURE_PRACTICAL,
            KEY_LECTURE_PRACTICAL_SHORT, KEY_LECTURE_DAY,
            KEY_LECTURE_DAY_SHORT, KEY_START_TIME, KEY_END_TIME,
            KEY_LOCATION, ADDITIONAL_INFO };
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_MODULES, columns, null, null,
            null, null, null);
    ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();

    int indexModCode = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_MODULE_CODE);

    int indexLectPracShort = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_LECTURE_PRACTICAL_SHORT);

    int indexLectDayShort = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_LECTURE_DAY_SHORT);
    int indexLectStart = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_START_TIME);

    int indexLectLoc = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_LOCATION);

    for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {
        results.add(c.getString(indexModCode) + " "
                + c.getString(indexLectPracShort) + " "
                + c.getString(indexLectDayShort) + " "
                + c.getString(indexLectStart) + " "
                + c.getString(indexLectLoc));
    }

    return results;
}
```

This works fine and here is how I populate my listview (`ModuleDatabaseHandler` is the class where the database is managed):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_modules_test);

    ModuleDatabaseHandler info = new ModuleDatabaseHandler(this);
    info.open();
    ArrayList<String> data = info.getData();
    info.close();

    l =  (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 ,data);
    l.setAdapter(adapter);
    l.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    }
```

I want to be able to click the `listView` item, and view **ALL the information** pertaining to the record (in the `listView` it only shows certain information). I have attempted to create a new method in the `ModuleDatabaseHandler` class called `getAllData`.

Below is the `OnItemClick` for the `ListView` item which launches a new activity, passing through the information from `getAllData` using `putExtra`:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

    TextView temp = (TextView) view;
    Toast.makeText(this, temp.getText() + " " + i, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show();

    ModuleDatabaseHandler info = new ModuleDatabaseHandler(this);
    info.open();
    String module_info = info.getAllData();   // METHOD TO GET ALL DATA
    info.close();

    Intent fullModuleDetails = new Intent();
    fullModuleDetails.setClassName("com.example.collegetimetable",
            "com.example.collegetimetable.ModuleDetails");

    fullModuleDetails.putExtra("list1", module_info);

    startActivity(fullModuleDetails);

}
```

Here is the `getAllData` method which retrieves **all** the information from the database. How could I alter this method, to retrieve **only** the information for the row relating to the particular `listView` item that was clicked by the user?

```
public String getAllData() {

    String[] columns = new String[]{ KEY_ROWID, KEY_MODULE_CODE, KEY_MODULE_NAME, KEY_LECTURE_PRACTICAL, KEY_LECTURE_DAY, KEY_START_TIME,KEY_END_TIME, KEY_LOCATION, ADDITIONAL_INFO};
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_MODULES, columns, null, null, null, null, null);

    String results = "";

    int indexRow = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
    int indexModCode = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_MODULE_CODE);
    int indexModName = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_MODULE_NAME);
    int indexLectPrac = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_LECTURE_PRACTICAL);

    int indexLectDay = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_LECTURE_DAY);

    int indexLectStart = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_START_TIME);
    int indexLectEnd = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_END_TIME);
    int indexLectLoc = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_LOCATION);
    int indexLectInfo = c.getColumnIndex(ADDITIONAL_INFO);


    for (c.moveToFirst();!c.isAfterLast();c.moveToNext()){
        results = results +  ( c.getString(indexModCode) +  " " + c.getString(indexModName) + " " + c.getString(indexLectPrac)
                + " " + c.getString(indexLectDay) + " " + c.getString(indexLectStart) + " " + c.getString(indexLectEnd) + " " 
                + c.getString(indexLectLoc) + " " + c.getString(indexLectInfo));
    }

    return results;
}
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of looping through the data, you would do something along the lines:

```
public String getAllDataForRow(int row) {

    String[] columns = new String[]{ KEY_ROWID, KEY_MODULE_CODE, KEY_MODULE_NAME, KEY_LECTURE_PRACTICAL, KEY_LECTURE_DAY, KEY_START_TIME,KEY_END_TIME, KEY_LOCATION, ADDITIONAL_INFO};
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_MODULES, columns, null, null, null, null, null);

    if(c.moveToPosition(row)) {
        String result = "";
        for(int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex<c.getColumnCount();columnIndex++) {
            result += c.getString(columnIndex)+" ";
        }
        return result;
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Row " + row + " does not exist");
    }
}
```

Also, if you didn't know: If you want all columns, you actually do not have to specify them in the projection, but can just pass null instead of columns.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Great - thanks..I got it working, I will also try your edit (which has alot less code - will try this now and let you know)

Comment: your edit works for me to, thanks, nice to know how to get all columns this way too.

Comment: I thought that if you want all columns and concatenate them into a string, then there's no point in adressing them by hand and the code becoms more readable.